# Change Blank Space Color of Scaled Wallpaper

Tags: gnome, themes, desktop-background, colors

If you set your wallpaper that is not the same scale as your screen, and set it to scaled mode on gnome-tweaks. You get a wallpaper with blank spaces. In windows, this blank spaces could be filled with solid color (other than black I mean). Is there any way to replicate this in ubuntu?  I already tried changing:
/org/gnome/desktop/background/primary-color to color that I want and
/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-opacity to 0.
And it didn't work, but something strange happened that the wallpaper preview on the setting does show the correct color.
[image]
Any help is appreciated.